# Scroll to Load More Method Freezes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableview that I'm trying to append data to when the user scrolls near the bottom. I've written this method to detect the scroll and it functions correctly but looks bad.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scroll {

NSInteger currentOffset = scroll.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger maximumOffset = scroll.contentSize.height - scroll.frame.size.height;


if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 5) {

        [self loaddata:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", celltitle.count]];

}
}
```

loaddata has a number passed to it which is used to limit the returning cells from the database correctly. i.e. LIMIT x, (x+20)

Like I said the data loads but each time it goes to load it the scrolling pauses and then resumes. The NSURLConnection is synchronous. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, synchronous operations will block the UI thread. You should read into Grand Central Dispatch, blocks, threading and asynchronous coding. Have look at this project: https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator

Comment: comment above should be an answer!